# Acceleo - Cross models reference with Java Application

Tags: java, acceleo

I am generating code starting from two related Metamodels. The main one has references to classes of the second one. The Acceleo execution works well when executed as an Acceleo plugin but not when executed as a Java application. If I start the Java main Class, data of the 2nd related metamodels are not visible.

The error I get is

```
org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.AcceleoEvaluationException: Unresolved compilation error in generation module
```

I show you a snippet of Debug mode. *target* is a reference to a class of the 2nd metamodel (named peersbehavior).

---- The URI is correct, it's pointing to the exact location ----
[image: exact URI]

---- But values are not retrieved ----

[image: empty object]

I had a similar problem with ATL Model2Model transformation: the option "Allow inter-model reference" must be checked. But in Acceleo I don't find anything similar

[EDIT]
As pointed by [standalone documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.acceleo.doc%2Fpages%2Freference%2Fstandalone.html),

I added these 2 rows of code at the Java class

```
public void registerResourceFactories(ResourceSet resourceSet) 
      {
        super.registerResourceFactories(resourceSet);
        // code added by me

        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("systembehavior", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("peerbehavior", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
       }
```

Now It works also starting the Java class, But if I export the project as Jar, and try to use it in another project, I have the same problem as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem adding this code (as pointed in the [EDIT] section of my question)

```
public void registerResourceFactories(ResourceSet resourceSet) 
      {
        super.registerResourceFactories(resourceSet);
        // code added by me

        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("systembehavior", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("peerbehavior", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
       }
```

and **adding manually the .emtl** compiled files, in the src dir (otherwise they will not be inserted in the .jar).

With these modification, the code generation works if executed as Java application. Running the transformation as Acceleo application doesn't work